# .htaccess rewrite root to get action

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code, its purpose is to direct the user to different `functions` depending on the action specified in a URL.

```
$action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

$action = strtolower($action);

switch ($action) {
  case 'viewproducts':
    viewProducts();
    break;
  case 'products':
    products();
    break;
  case 'homepage':
    homepage();
    break;
  default:
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        include_once("404.html");
}
```

I would like to direct the user to `homepage` if they are on the index or `/`.

```
RewriteEngine On
#if not a directory listed above, rewrite the request to ?action=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/$ index.php?action=homepage [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However when on `domain.com/` the switch defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not the `.htaccess` issue. It's your code. I would use this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

So all request just go straight to `index.php`, and in your "router" should be:

```
$action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : "homepage";
```

Because you setting `$action` to empty string if it's not specified, so switch defaults.

*P.S.: Just an advice. Do not build your own `CMS`, use frame or whatever. It's best to concentrate on your product than on development tools.*

**UPDATE**

As OP suggested, `RewriteRule` can be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hovewer, in my example `.htaccess` is from *HTML5 Boilerplate*, so it's tested and suitable for most cases (works for me as well).

Comment: thanks mate, changing the action how youve said works, its so simple!! I havent used your htaccess rule though as its not working. Instead have used `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]`. Update your question and I can accept? Also I understand in most scenario building a cms is inappropriate, however lots of bespoke functionallity needs to be build, the cms is just a small part of this product. Would you still advise frame?

Comment: Updated answer about your specific case. BTW, my `.htaccess` is boilerplate, so should work - probably something missing in your config.

Comment: Anyway, there's nothing wrong with building your own `CMS`, as long as the only thing you working on is actually your `CMS`. If you building other products (say, you're a freelancer) with your `CMS`, maintenance and support **will** become painful. It's good experience, but in real world I highly encourage you to use framework with it's most popular `CMS` (Symfony2 + Sonata, or Django with integrated one). Community support is priceless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?action=homepage [L,QSA]

#if not a directory listed above, rewrite the request to ?action=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```